# Simulate normal distributed data from genetic data in R

Tags: r, simulation, normal-distribution

I need to simulate data based on two random variables. Each random variable is a set of 0, 1 and 2 (genetic data). Following, there is an example of the variables for 10 observations:

Random var. 1:

```
v_1 = cbind(rep(rbinom(10,2,0.4)), rep(rbinom(10,2,0.4)), rep(rbinom(10,2,0.4)), rep(rbinom(10,2,0.4)), rep(rbinom(10,2,0.4)))
```

Random var. 2:

```
v_2 = cbind(rep(rbinom(10,2,0.4)), rep(rbinom(10,2,0.4)), rep(rbinom(10,2,0.4)), rep(rbinom(10,2,0.4)),  rep(rbinom(10,2,0.4)))
```

Those variables are normally distributed mean= 0 and variance=1 (or other value that I can choose). In addition, I also need to add term of error, normally distributed mean= 0 and variance=1.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: one variable is a sequence of 5 randomly drawn 0,1,2?

Comment: Yes, it is. Although this is a simplification, in my real data there are around of 1000.

Comment: I am a bit confused, the mean of a binomial distribution is p*n, which in your code would be 0.8 (0.4*2) and the variance p*n(1-p)= 0.8*0.2=0.16. What is the desired distribution for the 0,1,2? I sampled randomly in my example

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for you answer. I am still trying to define the problem. May be I was not clear enough to my question, so I post a new question in stats.stack.exchange https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/463952/simulate-normal-distributed-real-data-phenotypes-from-genotypic-data-in-r may be it help to define it better.

Answer (score 1):

I put the sequence in vectors, within a data.frame. You can change this if you like and put it in different columns.

```
n <- 100
t <- 5

library(data.table)
d <- data.table( 
  v1 = lapply(1:n, function(x) sample(0:2, t, replace = T) ),
  v2 = lapply(1:n, function(x) sample(0:2, t, replace = T) ),
  v1e = rnorm(n),
  v2e = rnorm(n)
)

head(d)

          v1        v2        v1e        v2e
1: 1,2,2,0,0 2,0,0,0,2 -0.3962995  0.9091728
2: 0,2,0,0,2 1,2,2,2,2 -2.5788875 -0.1007541
3: 0,1,1,0,0 2,0,1,1,0  0.7208587 -0.3362134
4: 1,0,2,0,2 0,1,1,0,2  0.6068573 -2.1755171
5: 1,0,0,0,0 2,2,2,1,2  0.2505764 -0.4038029
6: 2,2,1,1,1 2,0,0,1,0  0.1002509  0.9895424
```

Alternatively, you can add the error to the sequence of 0,1,2:

```
d <- data.table( 
  v1 = lapply(1:n, function(x) c(sample(0:2, t, replace = T), rnorm(1) )),
  v2 = lapply(1:n, function(x) c(sample(0:2, t, replace = T), rnorm(1) ))
)

                                                                  v1
1:  2.0000000, 1.0000000, 1.0000000, 1.0000000, 0.0000000,-0.2246831
2: 1.00000000,2.00000000,2.00000000,0.00000000,2.00000000,0.08186215
3:             1.000000,1.000000,2.000000,0.000000,2.000000,1.409102
4:        1.000000, 1.000000, 2.000000, 0.000000, 2.000000,-0.706325
5:  2.0000000, 2.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000,-0.7605603
6:        1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 2.000000, 0.000000,-1.805504
                                                                  v2
1:  1.0000000, 0.0000000, 2.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000,-0.8190068
2:             0.000000,2.000000,2.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.127785
3:                   1.00000,2.00000,0.00000,0.00000,0.00000,1.46689
4:        1.000000, 2.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,-0.963522
5:             1.000000,1.000000,2.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.122421
6:       2.0000000,0.0000000,0.0000000,1.0000000,2.0000000,0.8270646
```